# How to send Acknowledgement from server to device in hexa format?

Tags: java, sockets, gps, hex

can any one give idea about how to send acknowledgment from server to device. GPS(Global Positioning System ) sending one IMEI(International Mobile Equipment Identity) number and after that its needed acknowledgment in hexadecimal format(01).Once server send  acknowledgment then only we get raw-packet through socket programming.

Comment: what is the datatype of the value you want to send? String or int??

Comment: we have to send string data type

Answer (score 0):

```
int ack = 12;
String acknowledgement = Integer.toHexString(ack);
```

Comment: bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());sb = new StringBuffer(); if(buffer.length!=0){bis.read(buffer);  sb.append(new String(buffer));data=sb.toString();         BufferedOutputStream outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int ack = 01;String acknowledge = Integer.toHexString(ack);
outToClient.write(acknowledge.getBytes()); outToClient.flush();
bis.close();bis1 = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());    buffer1 = new byte[bis1.available()];sb = new StringBuffer();
if(buffer1.length!=0){bis1.read(buffer1);
sb.append(new String(buffer1));

Comment: see the above code i used . But the client is not  able to understanding the acknowledgment .please give me some more idea.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please any one help.. Am using above code but am sending acknowledgment the device is not able to understanding ...